# Application Required run as adminstrator first time

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, setup-deployment, windows

I have developed an application in c#.net.

Created a setup for windows 7 64 bit operating system. I have used Visual Studio 2010 to create a setup. I select the prerequisites for the application which are provided by default for 64 bit os setup namely Sql Server 2008 and .NET Framework 4.0.

The setup is installed successfully.

My problem is that **I need to run the application as administrator for first time.

Do I need to set specific properties for setup while creating the setup ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [Create and Embed an Application Manifest with Your Application.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) Have a look at this link and i hope you may get what you want. Making Your Application [UAC Aware](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17968/Making-Your-Application-UAC-Aware)